# What entities can decrypt Apple Pay token?

Tags: security, apple-pay

During Apple Pay payment, user device creates a payment token that contains a lot of encrypted information (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014929)). Among other things, there is a device-specific card number (vel `application PAN`).

Question is: which parties can see this identifier en route to Token Service Provider (who holds the actual card number). In particular, is this information available to merchant or acquirer in both online and offline (with a physical terminal) transactions?